# L5.1 - Command with localization not working (not in Ubuntu but yes on Mac)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a command called `SendReminders`, when I change the locale with `App::setLocale('locale')` *it looks like is working* because when I do `App::getLocale()` returns the correct one, but when I call for a translation returns always the default localization.

This is my **SendReminders** class:

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App;
use Exception;
use Storage;
use Lang;

class SendReminders extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'send:reminders';

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(){

        App::setLocale('EN');
        echo App::getLocale()."\n"; // <= Shows correctly 'EN'
        echo Lang::get('general.contact')."\n"; // <= Shows correctly 'Contact'

        App::setLocale('DE');
        echo App::getLocale()."\n"; // <= Shows correctly 'DE'
        echo Lang::get('general.contact')."\n"; // <= Doesn't show the correct value

    }

}
```

I'm missing something to make the localization work?

**EDIT:**

Some estrange behavior is happening because on my Mac is working but on Linux (Ubuntu) is not, looks like is not finding my folder `/resources/lang/de/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was because I set the locale with uppercase.

So, this is wrong:

```
App::setLocale('EN');
```

Should be:

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

**Explanation:**

Looks like **MacOS** is not case sensitive when you are talking about directories, so it doesn't matter if you do 'EN' or 'en' becasue it will find `/resources/lang/en/` without problem.

But if you do it on **Ubuntu** it will try to find exactly the folder with uppercase, and in this case, it doesn't exists.